# How can I detect relations between the tables in my UML?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, edmx, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm developing an application in C# using Visual Studio 2012 that must generate, among other things, a generic data model, an *.edmx file.  This program receives a UML model and transforms it into C# classes and data models in an MVC architecture, so, I haven't got the relations, PK's, FK's between tables.

My problem is to generate the relation between tables (Navigation Properties?). For each data resource (table), I must check if it has foreign keys and, if it does, generate the right code to create an edmx file correctly. Here's what I've got so far:

My edmxCodeGen class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DataComponent;

namespace codeGenAppMM2XulRdf
{
    public class edmxCodeGen
    {
        public static string toCS(AppDataModel appRDF)
        {
            StringBuilder csResult = new StringBuilder();

            csResult.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            csResult.AppendLine("<edmx:Edmx Version=\"3.0\" xmlns:edmx=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx\">");
            csResult.AppendLine("<!-- EF Runtime content -->");
            csResult.AppendLine("<edmx:Runtime>");
            csResult.AppendLine("<!-- SSDL content -->");
            csResult.AppendLine("<edmx:StorageModels>");

            csResult.AppendLine("  <Schema Namespace=\"BDClinicModel.Store\" Alias=\"Self\" Provider=\"System.Data.SqlClient\" ProviderManifestToken=\"2005\" xmlns:store=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl\">");
            csResult.AppendLine("    <EntityContainer Name=\"BDClinicModelStoreContainer\">");
            // ver namespace e container name nas duas linhas acima

            foreach (DataResource dr in appRDF.dataResources)
            {
                csResult.AppendLine("      <EntitySet Name=" + dr.ResourceClassName + " EntityType=\"BDClinicModel.Store." + dr.ResourceClassName + " store:Type=\"Tables\" Schema=\"dbo\" />");

            }

            csResult.AppendLine("      <EntitySet Name=\"sysdiagrams\" EntityType=\"BDClinicModel.Store.sysdiagrams\" store:Type=\"Tables\" Schema=\"dbo\" />");
            // sysdiagrams

            foreach (DataResource dr in appRDF.dataResources)
            {
                foreach (NavigationProperty np in dr.NavigationAttrs)
                {


                }
            }
            csResult.AppendLine("");
            csResult.AppendLine("");
            csResult.AppendLine("");
            csResult.AppendLine("");

            return csResult.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I intend to use the two final "foreach" cycles to write what I'm missing, something like this (from some other example in which I imported a database and the edmx was generated from it automatically):

```
  <AssociationSet Name="FK__consulta__id_mar__3493CFA7" Association="BDClinicModel.Store.FK__consulta__id_mar__3493CFA7">
    <End Role="marcacao" EntitySet="marcacao" />
    <End Role="consulta" EntitySet="consulta" />
  </AssociationSet>
  <AssociationSet Name="FK__consulta__id_pro__3587F3E0" Association="BDClinicModel.Store.FK__consulta__id_pro__3587F3E0">
    <End Role="processo" EntitySet="processo" />
    <End Role="consulta" EntitySet="consulta" />
  </AssociationSet>
...
```

Problem is, how do I detect the relations? I think I must iterate through the data resources and check (maybe?) the navigation properties, but I can't see how.

Can someone help please? Any ideas?

Thanks, Chiapa

Comment: Does your database contain foreign-key constraints you can use?  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp Failing that, are the PK's and FK's named in such a way that you can match them?

Comment: This program receives a UML model and transforms it into C# classes and data models in an MVC architecture, so, I haven't got the relations, PK's, FK's or whatever. I managed to create all the controllers, views and models but I need the edmx.

Comment: If your UML model doesn't contain this information, or information from which the relations can be derived, I don't see how it can be done.  Presumably the edmx represents an actual database; do you also create the database, or does it already exist?

Comment: The UML model that's received contains the classes diagram. From that I generate C# classes and all the other stuff

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the original title of this question would attract more potential helpers as they would see exactly what the issue was. Detecting relations in a database can be very broad as databases are present almost in all kinds of programming. Am I right?

Comment: Your original title will attract Google searchers trying to find out how to generate an EDMX.  It's not representative of your actual question.  However, feel free to put in a title that better represents your actual problem, if you have one.  Note that you have the C# and EDMX tags on your question already.

Comment: I think you nailed it this time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to detect the relations this way:

```
        foreach (UMLRelationship rel in umlDomainModel.UMLClassRelationships)
        {
            if (rel.relType == Enum_TypeOfRelation.aggregation || rel.relType == Enum_TypeOfRelation.association || rel.relType == Enum_TypeOfRelation.composition)
            { 
                csResult.AppendLine("");
...
```

This way I iterate through all the relations of the UML domain model to check afterwards if the relation type is one of the three (aggregation, association or composition). If it is, then the relation exists and I can use the roles and classes associated.

Thanks